# scope variable becomes blank after assigned to ng-model in select list

Tags: angularjs

Hi  I have a angular controller like as below

```
adm.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.selectedItem = '13';
}]);
```

And I have a cshtml file which hold a kendo drop down and this have following line.

```
<div>
{{selectedItem}}
<select id="ddlParameter" k-options="datasourceName"  ng-model="selectedItem" data-role="dropdownlist" />
</div>
```

Now dropdown is successfully bind with elements of datasource. when I see output of this html file, nothing selected in dropdown and even expression (enclosed in {{}} brackets) also not displayed any value.
Now I remove ng-model from dropdown, expression (enclosed in {{}} brackets) getting resolve and its display 13 on browser.
please tell what is the problem and how this is inter-related..

Comment: create a plunker for your issue

Answer (score 0):

You must provide further information to pinpoint the problem. All your source in a plunker would be a good move.

But from what you've provided I can guess if your data for the select provides integers as option values you must feed an integer to $scope.selectedItem for it to preselect an option.
Also why don't you use the native ng-options directive?
something like:

```
<select id="ddlParameter" ng-options="row.value as row.name for (key, row) in datasourceName track by key"  ng-model="selectedItem" data-role="dropdownlist" />
```